# Index a file of term-count pairs in lucene

Tags: lucene

I have a collection of term-count pairs that I want to index in lucene.
Is there any way to do this without creating a "document" where I have 
replicated each term as many times as the count?

My query will also be of similar form.

---

My question was probably not clear. What I meant is that instead of a full document I have the term-count values. E.g., instead of the document "a rose is a rose is a rose" I have a file of the form:

a 3
rose 3
is 2

If I have a query of the form "rose a rose", I will represent it as 
rose 2
a 1

Can I use lucene to index this kind of data to start with? And then can I query with this type of queries?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should be simple to achieve. Just create a document with two fields -- one holding the term, the other holding the count. You'll probably benefit by using NumericField for the count.